# How to generate columns from a list of column in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have dataframe like this:

```
  Date       ID     Age      Gender        Fruits
  1.1.19     1      50         F            Apple
  2.1.19     1      50         F            Mango
  2.1.19     1      50         F            Orange
  1.1.19     2      75         M            Grapes
  4.1.19     3      20         M            Apple
  4.1.19     3      20         M            Grapes
```

for example i have two lists:

```
fruits_list = ['Apple', 'Mango', 'Orange', 'Grapes', 'Banana', 'Guava']
date_list = ['1.1.19', '2.1.19', '3.1.19', '4.1.19', '5.1.19', '6.1.19']
```

I want to convert the Fruit column into further columns which gives binary info yes/no for each person. 
 And the missing date should be NaN. by using this

```
pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Fruits'], prefix='', prefix_sep='').groupby('Date').max()
```

i will get this but i need all the elements which are in **fruit_list** and **date_list**

```
Date          ID     Age      Gender        Apple    Mango      Orange    Grapes 
1.1.19         1      50         F            1        0           0         0
1.1.19         2      75         M            0        0           0         1
2.1.19         1      50         F            0        1           1         0 
3.1.19         NaN    NaN        NaN          NaN     NaN        NaN       NaN
4.1.19         3      20         M            1        0           0         1
```

Desired output would be like this.

```
Date             ID     Age      Gender        Apple    Mango      Orange    Grapes    Banana   Guava   sum
    1.1.19         1      50         F            1        0           0         0     0        0       1 
    1.1.19         2      75         M            0        0           0         1     0        0       1
    2.1.19         1      50         F            0        1           1         0     0        0       2
    3.1.19         NaN    NaN        NaN          0        0           0         0     0        0       0
    4.1.19         3      20         M            1        0           0         1     0        0       2
    5.1.19         NaN    NaN        NaN          0        0           0         0     0        0       0
    6.1.19         NaN    NaN        NaN          0        0           0         0     0        0        0
```

Comment: @jezrael  can you help?

Answer (score 3):

First is necessary datetimes in `date_list` and `Date` column for avoid missing values, then use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for add not exist Datetimes and columns:

```
df1 = (pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Fruits'], prefix='', prefix_sep='')
         .groupby('Date')
         .max()
         .reindex(index=date_list, columns=fruits_list, fill_value=0)
         .assign(sum = lambda x: x.sum(axis=1)))
print (df1)

        Apple  Mango  Orange  Grapes  Banana  Guava  sum
Date                                                    
1.1.19      1      0       0       1       0      0    2
2.1.19      0      1       1       0       0      0    2
3.1.19      0      0       0       0       0      0    0
4.1.19      1      0       0       1       0      0    2
5.1.19      0      0       0       0       0      0    0
6.1.19      0      0       0       0       0      0    0
```

Then add original columns by [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and change order of columns by `reindex`:

```
cols = ['Date','ID','Age','Gender'] + fruits_list
df = df1.reset_index().merge(df, on='Date', how='left').reindex(cols, axis=1)
print (df)
     Date   ID   Age Gender  Apple  Mango  Orange  Grapes  Banana  Guava
0  1.1.19  1.0  50.0      F      1      0       0       1       0      0
1  1.1.19  2.0  75.0      M      1      0       0       1       0      0
2  2.1.19  1.0  50.0      F      0      1       1       0       0      0
3  2.1.19  1.0  50.0      F      0      1       1       0       0      0
4  3.1.19  NaN   NaN    NaN      0      0       0       0       0      0
5  4.1.19  3.0  20.0      M      1      0       0       1       0      0
6  4.1.19  3.0  20.0      M      1      0       0       1       0      0
7  5.1.19  NaN   NaN    NaN      0      0       0       0       0      0
8  6.1.19  NaN   NaN    NaN      0      0       0       0       0      0
```

Comment: Cool. I forget to mention in my question, can we also get the sum of all the columns?

Comment: Here i lose the person attributes like age and gender?

Comment: when i use that logic then i am getting all the values 0 (NaN)

Comment: @s_khan92 - Problem is with `df1`, first paragraph?

Comment: @s_khan92 - Are datetimes in `Date` column and also are datetiems in list `date_list` ?

Comment: yes but there are some missing values but thats why there i would like NaN

Comment: @s_khan92 - what is `print (type(date_list[0]))` ?

Comment: `<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>`

Comment: @s_khan92 - It is good, also `print (type(df['Date'].iloc[0]))` ?

Comment: thats same `pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp`

Comment: @s_khan92 - what is `print (np.intersect1d(df['Date'], date_list))` ? This is for test if some datetimes are in both Dates and `date_list`

Comment: i dont understand why this `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'int'`

Comment: @s_khan92 - hmm, hard question, but it seems in real data `date_list` are different datetime like in Date column, so missing values

Comment: @s_khan92 - Is possible test it by `print (pd.DatetimeIndex(date_list).intersection(df['Date']))` ?

Comment: @s_khan92 - So problem with sample data? Or only with real?

Comment: Actually the problem come only when i use this `df1 = (pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Fruits'], prefix='', prefix_sep='')
         .groupby('Date')
         .max()
         .reindex(index=date_list, columns=fruits_list, fill_value=0)
         .assign(sum = lambda x: x.sum(axis=1)))` but when i use normal this `pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Fruits'], prefix='', prefix_sep='').groupby('Date').max()` then evrything is fine so problem come when i have to use lists as index

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213085/discussion-between-jezrael-and-s-khan92).